# Opencart new module is not showing in the list

Tags: opencart, mailchimp, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am a top administrator and the user group has all the permissions checked. I installed Mailchimp Pro but its not showing in the list. When I used the Mailchimp demo's relative path of the module on my store, it says -

"Permission Denied! 
You do not have permission to access this page, please refer to your system administrator."

Comment: Check If module is compatible with your opencart version?

Comment: @Mojtaba Sabeti - Yes, it is compatible with the version.

Comment: Did you updated the permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow below steps:

1. Go to the Admin->System->Users->User Group.
2. Then edit your user group.
3. On the Edit page, search for your Mailchimp Pro module file name and select the
   checkbox and then save.
4. Now check your Module again.

I hope this helps.